# Discord Bot shall delete "user pinned message to channel" message

Tags: bots, discord.js

I'm kinda new to programming a discord bot, but now I have a problem and can't find a solution.
I'm not even sure which language I'm using - I work in Atom, start my bot with node index.js and use functions / classes / ... from here:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

**My problem**

However, with a specific command my bot sends a message to a certain channel and pins it. But I want the bot to delete the system message that says "user pinned message to channel" (it has to be something like that, my discord isn't in english), but I somehow can't get that message.

**What I tried**

I tried to get it like that:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${BOT} hat eine nachricht an diesen kanal angeheftet`) { somefunction}
```

where BOT is <@ Bot ID> and "hat eine nachricht an diesen kanal angeheftet" is kinda the german version of "pinned message to channel", but nothing happens. It doesn't execute somefunction (tested it with `message.channel.send(something)`)

Then I thought I could use `fetchMessages()` (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) like that:

```
function botAngeheftet(message, planungsChannel) {
  let mes = planungsChannel.fetchMessages({limit:1})
    .then(messages => planungsChannel.send("TEST:\n" + messages.first())
    .catch(console.error);
```

but then the message in planungsChannel is

```
TEST:
```

without any message. I changed the limit to 2 and wrote something in planungsChannel (sometext), executed the function again and the result was

```
TEST:
sometext
```

So.. fetchMessages() seems to work - but not for the system message.

**My question**

How can I "get" that system message to work with it? Or: How can I have the bot delete that system message saying "user pinned message to channel" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a theoretical solution (untested) but it should work.**

Each `message` on discord has a `type` property, which falls under a couple of types, you can see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageType). The specific `type` you can use in this case is if `message.type === "PINS_ADD"`, which is the `type` of the

> the system message that says "user pinned message to channel"

that you were referring to.

Put simply, all you have to do is:

```js
on msg event (msg) 
     if(msg.type === "PINS_ADD") msg.delete();
```

This is the pseudocode not actual code, hopefully you can convert it.
[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=type)

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) But that way it will delete ALL system messages with type PINS_ADD. I added a check about the channel that message was sent in, so now it will delete these messages only in that specific channel. It's enough for my purpose now, but is there a way to check for the user that was mentioned in the message? I might want the bot only to delete the system messages from pinned messages that the bot pinned.

Comment: Well it is just the same `message` object, so you can check for the `author` and then the `bot` property. Translated: `message.author.bot` or just check id `message.author.id === "idhere"`
Remember that all this is [documented](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: Ah okay, I just assumed that the author of the system message is some kind of discord thing :/ Thanks a lot, it now works just as I want it to :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help

Comment: To make it even easier for beginners or lazy people :P, the code is as follows:
`client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.type === "PINS_ADD" && message.author.bot) message.delete();
}`

Answer (score 0):

The type of the message that is sent when a message is pinned is 'CHANNEL_PINNED_MESSAGE'.

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {

  if (message.author.bot && message.type === 'CHANNEL_PINNED_MESSAGE') {
    message.delete();
  }

}
```